# ¿Existe una traducción aceptable para "grid" en español?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

En [esta pregunta de Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114076/como-programo-listar-una-grilla-con-un-datareader-sin-que-me-den-problemas-los) se habla de "grilla", la cual es una traducción que he visto en varias ocasiones para *grid*:

> ¿Como programo listar una grilla con un datareader sin que me den problemas los eventsargs y los eventsargscells?

Esto hizo recordar una discusión que escuché algún día. Lo que se decía es que "grilla" no es una traducción válida. A modo jocoso alguien decía: *grilla es la esposa del grillo*. Y de hecho, en el DLE se encuentra una única acepción para grillo (ignorando las expresiones con esa palabra):

> [**grillo, lla**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JXpqXOD)
>
> *Del lat. grillus.*
>
> 1. m. y f. Insecto ortóptero saltador, de unos tres centímetros de largo, color negro rojizo, con una mancha amarilla en el arranque de las alas, cabeza redonda y ojos muy prominentes, cuyo macho sacude y roza con tal fuerza los élitros, que produce un sonido agudo y monótono. U. en m. ref. a la especie.

Hasta donde recuerdo, la propuesta era usar **rejilla**, en lugar de grilla, pero siento que no es muy usada esa palabra en este contexto.

¿Es grilla una traducción válida para *grid*? ¿Se entiende o usa en otras lugares?

Comment: Según los usos normales de *grid* hay una plétora de traducciones según el significado, pero de las que me salen en el diccionario, reconozco todas: *cuadro, cuadrícula, red, rejilla, guardaganado, enrejado*. El diccionario me da *parrilla* y *grilla* para indicar la zona de inicio para una carrera, pero no parecen encajar con lo que se describe en la pregunta enlazada. *Rejilla* suelo ver en contextos de servidores como traducción de *rack* ¿Podrías indicar exactamente qué es lo que se quiere decir con *grilla* en la pregunta? Ningún de los significados me parecen coherentes con esa pregunta.

Comment: @guifa este es un [ejemplo](https://www.google.com/search?q=whats+a+datagrid+.net&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu3NLYu57XAhURziYKHbhdD_IQ_AUIBigB#mhpiv=2)

Comment: ¿Y tabla no vale?

Comment: @guifa Creo que en un contexto de programación la mayoría asociaría Tabla con otro concepto (elemento de base de datos)

Comment: En inglés para el interfaz de Android existen por ejemplo TableView y GridView, y son diferentes, los que has enseñado son más en plan TableView. Obviamente no puedo controlar lo que diga la gente, pero tampoco que me parezcan raras algunas traducciones informáticas jaja ;-)

Comment: Interesante lo que me cuentas de TableView y GridView en Android, no sabía. Quizá la imagen no fue el mejor ejemplo ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En España no decimos *grilla*, lo conocemos por compañeros de profesión hispanoamericanos pero los que no se dediquen a la informática o alguna profesión donde se utilice ese término seguramente no lo entiendan.

Lo que aparece en los ejemplos que has puesto lo llamaríamos **tabla** sin lugar a dudas:

[image]

A un *grid* de este tipo lo denominamos **cuadrícula** o quizá **rejilla** también:

[image]

Cuando hablamos de *grid layout* decimos **rejilla**, incluso la nueva funcionalidad en las herramientas de desarrollador de Firefox lo llama así:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Siendo de Argentina y trabajando a diario con programadores, puedo testimoniar que *grilla* es la traducción habitual del inglés *grid* (es, por ejemplo, como se llama al tipo de elemento visual que se utilizaba en Visual Basic a través del control MSFLXGRD.OCX). El DLE no recoge este significado, pero por supuesto no es el único caso en que una palabra realmente en uso no aparece en el DLE.

En el Wikcionario sí aparece *[grilla](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/grilla)*, aunque no refiriéndose a este tipo de elemento específicamente. Propio de Argentina es el significado de "rejilla, esquema o cuadro de programación" (en televisión); en las ciencias *grilla* es "cuadrícula, conjunto de los cuadrados que resultan de cortarse perpendicularmente dos series de rectas paralelas".

Creo que este último significado técnico autorizaría a referirse a una *grid* como *grilla*, por extensión, pero también es cierto que en otros países de habla hispana *grilla* tiene otros significados, en algunos casos peyorativos, por lo cual no sé cómo se oirá el término allí.

Comment: Precisamente en Colombia grilla tiene además un uso peyorativo, aunque en un contexto profesional no hay riesgo de confusión.

Answer (score 2):

No me parece serio emplear a la hembra del grillo para lo que es una [retícula o rejilla](http://www.tugurium.com/gti/termino.php?Tr=grid)

Si un diccionario no proporciona una traducción directa hay que buscar en el propio idioma alguna palabra que describa el término en cuestión, y el español es rico en palabras.

---

Creo que mi comentario (jocoso?) sobre la hembra del grillo no se ha entendido. Y reconozco que no busqué en el diccionario de americanismos. Paso a explicarme mejor.

Un 'grid', al menos desde España es una retícula, rejilla o cuadrícula, lo que no obsta para que muchos usen el término inglés con total libertad, en muchos casos porque no se han molestado en buscar en un diccionario inglés-español.

Otro uso reside en la tecnología de computo intensiva donde se coordinan recursos computacionales heterogéneos (ordenadores, clusters, supercomputadores, almacenamiento en red, etc.) situados en distintos dominios administrativos (distintas organizaciones, empresas, etc.) y, por tanto, no sujetos a un control centralizado, lo que se conoce como 'grid computing' (computación reticular).

Comment: Trato de no ser muy españolista (si se me permite el término). La razón de apuntar los términos rejilla, retícula o, incluso, cuadrícula, deviene del hecho de que en el área en que nos movemos, la informática en este caso, al ser un campo nuevo, con una total influencia anglosajona, deberíamos buscar unas traducciones/adaptaciones lo más genéricas posibles, para todo el espectro de hablantes del español.